# Find and Update nested level

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to find and update the value of a **quantity to 3** where my **id is "5cc6d9737760963ea07de411"**

**my data:**

```
[
    {
        "products" : [ {
                    "id" : "5cc6d9737760963ea07de411",
                    "quantity" : 1,
                    "totalPrice" : 100,
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "5cc6d9737760963ea07de412",
                    "quantity" : 2,
                    "totalPrice" : 200,
                }
        ],
        "isCompleted" : false,
        "_id" : "5cc7e4096d7c2c1f03570a2f"
    },
    {
        "products" : [{
                    "id" : "5cc6d9737760963ea07de414",
                    "quantity" : 1,
                    "totalPrice" : 100,
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "5cc6d9737760963ea07de4133",
                    "quantity" : 2,
                    "totalPrice" : 200,
                }
        ],
        "isCompleted" : false,
        "_id" : "5cc7e4096d7c2c1f03570a2f"
    }

]
```

i tried:

```
Schema.findOneAndUpdate({_id: ""},{ "products": {"quantity": 3}})
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Try `Schema.findOneAndUpdate({ "products.id": "5cc6d9737760963ea07de411" },{ "products": {"quantity": 3}})`

Comment: @holydragon its remove all product data and put  `{"quantity": 3}`

Comment: Add $set to it  `Schema.findOneAndUpdate({ "products.id": "5cc6d9737760963ea07de411" },{ $set: {"products": {"quantity": 3}}})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `.dot` notation along with the [**`$`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) positional operator here

```
Schema.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "products.id": "5cc6d9737760963ea07de411" },
  { "products.$.quantity": 3 }
)
```